# CentOS 7 PATH overwritten by /etc/bashrc

Tags: bash, path

I have a Dell server running CentOS 7. I installed the iDRAC remote access tools from Dell, and it reset my PATH variable.

Some more details:
I have a script in `/etc/profiles.d` which adds something to the PATH

The DELL iDRACTools install script is run as with sudo and has the following line:

`echo "PATH=$PATH:/opt/dell/srvadmin/sbin" >> /etc/bashrc`

But it appears that when this install script is actually run, the PATH variable doesn't have the values which I had earlier appended to it. The final result is that PATH doesn't have all the values that were set in my `/etc/profiles.d` script.

To solve the problem I will just remove the line from `/etc/bashrc`. However, for my understanding I would like to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the path string is in double quotes the `$PATH` variable is expanded by the shell and then `echo`ed and appended to `/etc/bashrc`.
This means `PATH` is set to the actual value of `$PATH` when the install script is run plus `/opt/dell/srvadmin/sbin` and not to a literal `$PATH:/opt/dell/srvadmin/sbin`.

I don't know if this is intended or a bug. You could replace the line with

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/dell/srvadmin/sbin
```

in `/etc/bashrc` or change the double quotes in the script with single quotes to avoid `$PATH` from being expanded:

```
echo 'PATH=$PATH:/opt/dell/srvadmin/sbin' >> /etc/bashrc
```